# Firebase Rules - Shared User Contracts and User Specific Contracts

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I'm working on a contracting app between contractors and employers. I'm now working on the contract itself.

I've thought of this from the perspective of both creating a messaging app and a game like the Happy-Angry-Surprised example firebase app.

What I have now is a contract node `/contracts/`. There can only be 2 users in a contract. Much like 2 people playing a game or in a chat.

```
/contracts/contractKey/employerID
/contracts/contractKey/contractorID
/contracts/contractKey/metadata
```

There is a separate dashboard for the contractor and employer. I want to be able to show each type of user their specific contracts.

I have a `/users/` node that has a mix of both types of users but each one has a role `/users/role`

I was thinking about `/users/uid/contracts/contractKey:true`.

Here is the actual problem/question:

I would write these joins out to each user when the contract is created. However, the employer always initiates/creates the contract when they are logged in. In order to write the join I have to let them write to the /users/uid node that will contain one that is their node and one that is not.

This is to be able to add this data: `/users/uid/contracts/contractKey:true.`

How could I go about either structuring this better or writing the write rules to prevent giving employers access to all the contractors data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I dove in to Firebase Cloud Functions which is amazing by the way! The best way to handle this is server side that way I can keep data more secure on the client side.

Here is what I came up with:

```
exports.fanContract = functions.database.ref('/contracts/{contract_id}/')
.onWrite(event => {
  // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
  const original = event.data.val();
  const contractorID = original.contractorID;

  console.log('moving', event.params, original);

  // You must return a Promise when performing asynchronous tasks inside a Functions such as
  // writing to the Firebase Realtime Database.

  return admin.database().ref(`/users/${contractorID}/contracts/${event.params.contract_id}`).set(original);
});
```

Here is how it works. Whenever a write event happens on the database to the /contracts/contract_id node an event is triggered which runs the firebase function "fanContract."

It will grab the data that was written and the contractID in the contract. Then we can use the Admin SDK to ref where to copy the data to. We can use the contractor id and the event params to grab the contract ID. That way I can neatly store every users contracts under their user information.

This will make life easier when I need to present the user with their contract information. The next step is being able to update the contract and maintaining concurrency.